NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='InputPrefix']"}
when i created seperate stepdefinition classes like Given, When,Then the automation script usin findElement etc.. is not reading in when and then step.js  but its reading in given.js file what mistake happened tell me.
I want the flow of run continued from Given Stepdefinition js file to When and Then js file
i tried to connect by creating seperate js file in root directory for taking xpath for the element .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide more details regarding the issue with links and relevant attachements or the error log. Unable to answer above question wihout those. Can provide general answer only. Explain in more specific.
